# How to install xtext 2.12 as a plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

Eclipse oxygen 2 **DSL** package comes with **XText** 2.12. However if i try to install **XText** on existing eclipse base, i get **XText** 2.13. How do i get 2.12 for installing on oxygen 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the xtext update site you can find many versions. you need to untick "show latest only" http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/

and you can download zipped update sites here https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/downloads/

Comment: Thanks a ton Christian.